# Swift Playgrounds Apple Everyone Can Code App Exercise

Tags: swift

I'm trying to figure out why this particular code won't pass in the playground, I"m working through the Everyone Can Code App Development with Swift course from Apple.  Here's the challenge:

Now that users can log in, they need to be able to search through a list of users to find their friends. This might normally be done by having the user enter a name, and then looping through all user names to see if a user name contains the search term entered. You'll learn about loops later, so for now you'll just work through one cycle of that. Imagine you are searching for a friend whose user name is StepChallenger. You enter "step" into a search bar and the app begins to search. When the app comes to the user name "stepchallenger," it checks to see if "StepChallenger" contains "step."

Using userName and searchName below, write an if-else statement that checks to see if userName contains the search term. The search should not be case sensitive.

Here's my code:

```
import Foundation
let userName = "StepChallenger"
let searchName = "step"

if userName.contains("step") && userName.lowercased() == searchName  {
print("We have found the user")

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I apologize if I'm not doing this correctly.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should write `userName.lowercased().contains("step")` instead.

Comment: and you should use || instead of &&, although you don't really need the second part, since .contains will also catch it if they are equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not printing anything because the result of the `if` is `false`. Let's check why

- Your first condition `userName.contains("step")`

your `userName` is "StepChallenger" and you are checking if it contains "step". **It doesn't**, because you are not doing a case-insensitive check. So the first condition has already returned `false` making the whole `if` condition evaluate to `false` since you are using `&&`.

- Your second condition `userName.lowercased()` is "stepchallenger" and you are checking if it **equal to** "step". No it is not the same string, so again it returns `false`.

So in the end the `print` statement is never executed. What you need to do to check if the `userName` contains `searchName` is to convert everything to the same case and use the `contains` method.

```
if userName.lowercased().contains(searchName.lowercased()) {
    print("User found!")
}
```

Alternatively there is a [caseInsensitiveCompare(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414769-caseinsensitivecompare) check method you can check out.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be:

```
if userName.lowercased().contains(searchName) {
    print("We have found the user")
}
```

Instead of:

```
if userName.contains("step") && userName.lowercased() == searchName  {
    print("We have found the user")
}
```

Because .lowercased() essentially turns "StepChallenger" into "stepchallenger", then the .contains(searchName) checks whether "stepchallenger" contains "step".